# Error with appendPixelBuffer: withPresentationTime:

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an issue with my AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. After a while(this time can vary from 10 seconds to 60 seconds), appendPixelBuffer: withPresentationTime: returns NO with the following error:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x16520f50 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x16527f90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12780.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780)}

Please don't redirect me to another question here on stackoverflow. Because there is no answers out there for me. No, I'm not appending two frames at the same time. Logged the time several times.

I'm using real time data and the writerInput expects it.

And this error only happens if set a movieFragmentInterval for my AVAssetWriter and only on my iPhone 5s, and I've tested on different iPhone 5s with different iOS versions (7.1 and 7.0.5/6). But working fine on earlier phones. If I comment out that line it all works. But I need a movieFragmentInterval for a important purpose in my app. And this I set right after like this,

```
    _writer = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:recordingFileURL fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:error];
_writer.movieFragmentInterval = CMTimeMake(3, 1);
```

And my other code looks something like this.

```
- (BOOL)writeVideoFrameAtTime:(CMTime)time image:(CGImageRef)image error:(NSError **)error {

if (!_started) {
_started = YES;
CRDebug(@"Start writing");
[_writer startWriting];
[_writer startSessionAtSourceTime:time];
[_video startSessionWithPresentationTime:time];
}

if (![_writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
 CRDebug(@"Not ready for more data (video)");
return NO;
}

if (!_pixelBuffer) {
 CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, _bufferAdapter.pixelBufferPool, &_pixelBuffer);
if (status != kCVReturnSuccess) {
  if (_writer.error) {
    if (error) *error = _writer.error;
    CRWarn(@"Error creating pixel buffer: %@", _writer.error);
  } else {
    CRSetError(error, 0, @"Error creating pixel buffer");
  }
  return NO;
}
}

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer, 0);
uint8_t *pixels = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer);
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image);
CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
CFDataGetBytes(imageData, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(imageData)), pixels);

if (_bufferAdapter && ![_bufferAdapter appendPixelBuffer:_pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time]) {
if (_writer.error) {
  if (error) *error = _writer.error;
  CRWarn(@"Error appending pixel buffer: %@", _writer.error);
} else {
  CRSetError(error, 0, @"Error appending pixel buffer");
}
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer, 0);
  CFRelease(imageData);
  return NO;
}

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer, 0);
CFRelease(imageData);
return YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Contacted apple regarding this issue and they wanted me to file it as a bug report. Will do that as soon as possible and get back to all of you guys when I know more.

Comment: any comment back, or do you have the bug # to track?

Comment: still exists in iOS 9.0.2 !!!

Answer (score 4):

I'm running into this exact same problem. When I combine `AVFileTypeMPEG4` with `movieFragmentInterval` it randomly results in the same error message you're seeing. I've put logging in all aspects of the asset writing and I'm also definitely not writing duplicate samples.

I did finally get it to work by changing `AVFileTypeMPEG4` to `AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie`. I can reliably reproduce it (albeit the time it takes is random) with MPEG4, but QuickTime seems to always work without error. I know that's not necessarily a solution to your problem if you really want mp4 files, but I thought I'd share my findings.

Comment: I would've used a comment, if I was allowed.

Comment: this answer is help so +1. Quicktime with intervall or mp4 without, both work, any other might cause trouble